# ms sql Query for POS item sales

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question regarding POS system item sales data. In the database, there is a "Totals" table. In that table, contains various records identified by the "TtlType" field. I'm working with 2 types. Values 11, which is the Item POS Sales, and 12, which is the Item Cost Sales.

When I do my SQL Query, i'm doing something along the lines of

```
SELECT ItemNumber,
       SUM(ItemCount),
       SUM(ItemAmount)
FROM Totals 
WHERE TtlType = 11 
      AND Date = 8/1/2012
```

etc.

I'd like to also include TtlType 12. How can I merge all of the data into one row?

If I change my WHERE to include TtlType 11 & 12, I get 2 seperate rows for each menu item. The first one being TtlType 11 which is the Sell Price, and the next being 12 which is the cost. BOTH TtlType use the SAME field names to record information (ItemCount, ItemAmount)

I hope i explained this well enough. When I use the GROUP BY, I still get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your data structure fully, or the significance of ItemNumber.

However, you don't need a GROUP BY to do SUM as you already know, but including ItemNumber in your SELECT & GROUP BY will definitely cause you to have duplicate rows as it will be grouped on that column.

You shouldn't have any issues with the two SUM functions with just

```
SELECT SUM(ItemCount), SUM(ItemAmount) FROM Totals WHERE TtlType IN (11,12) 
AND Date = 8/1/2012
```